# handling http multipart response

Tags: java, scala

Soap web service returns a multipart response with max 5 files. Each file of around 60-70 MB. 
When I try to read the response input stream it takes a very long time. Like 3 minutes to read response having one file (60 MB).

I tired reading input stream char by char, using byte array buffer, Also tried apache IOUtils.toString(is) and guava API to read input stream but the time taken is still the same.

```
var respBody: Option[String] = None
var multipart: Option[MimeMultipart] = None
if (contentType.equals("multipart/related")) {

// this line of code is taking time `enter code here`
  val dataSource = new 
  ByteArrayDataSource(response.getEntity.getContent, contentType)

//enter code here

  multipart = Some(new MimeMultipart(dataSource))
  respBody = Some(multipart.get.getBodyPart(0).getContent.toString)
}
```

should be able to read response input stream to string in less time as SATA is less (60 MB)

Comment: I think `333 kBps = 2.667 mbps` is a decent download speed.

Comment: If this is in Scala, Akka Streams are always a good place to start when streaming data to/from the internet. This will still be limited to your personal upload/download speed though, no matter how efficient your actual code is.